# I can't put a list of expansion panels from on_start to a screen

Tags: python, kivy, widget

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelOneLine
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

gui = """
Screen:
    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Welcome'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
        
    MDNavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            WelcomeScreen: 
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcome'
    id: welcome
    
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: main
        
"""
md_list = [('List', 'The class MDList in combination with a BaseListItem like OneLineListItem will create a list that '
            'expands as items are added to it, working nicely with Kivy’s ScrollView.'),
           ('Banner', 'A banner displays a prominent message and related optional actions.')]


class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcome'))


class MyProject(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(gui)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        for i in md_list:
            self.manager.get_screen('welcome').ids.main.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon='calendar-text-outline',
                    content=MDLabel(text=i[1]),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(
                        text=i[0])))


MyProject().run()
```

This gave me:

```
 File "C:\Users\Hermi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\main.py", line 52, in on_start
     self.manager.get_screen('welcome').ids.main.add_widget(
 AttributeError: 'MyProject' object has no attribute 'manager'

I have tried self.root.ids.main.add_widget, and got: 
File "C:\Users\Hermi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\main.py", line 52, in on_start
     self.root.ids.main.add_widget(
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

I really don't understand how to navigate the widget tree. I've been looking all over.
How can I place the expansion panels on the `WelcomeScreen`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be rather

```
sm.get_screen('welcome')
```

instead of

```
self.manager.get_screen('welcome')
```

but `sm.get_screen('welcome').ids` is empty and it doesn't have `main`.

Problem is that you have two `WelcomeScreen` - one created with `sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcome'))` and second created in `kv`

You don't need first `WelcomeScreen`

And second `WelcomeScreen` can be accessed with

```
self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen('welcome')`
```

and it has `.ids.main`

```
    def on_start(self):

        #welcome = sm.get_screen('welcome')
        welcome = self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen('welcome')

        main_grid = welcome.ids.main

        print(welcome.ids)

        for i in md_list:
            main_grid.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon='calendar-text-outline',
                    content=MDLabel(text=i[1]),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(
                        text=i[0])))
```

---

Full working code.

I added function in `class WelcomeScreen(Screen):` to show that it doesn't need `sm = ScreenManager()`

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelOneLine
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

gui = """
Screen:
    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Welcome'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
        
    MDNavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            WelcomeScreen: 
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            
<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcome'
    id: welcome
    
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: main
        
"""
md_list = [('List', 'The class MDList in combination with a BaseListItem like OneLineListItem will create a list that '
            'expands as items are added to it, working nicely with Kivy’s ScrollView.'),
           ('Banner', 'A banner displays a prominent message and related optional actions.')]

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    def stackoverflow(self):
        print("Stackoverflow TEST")


class MyProject(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(gui)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):

        welcome = self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen('welcome')
        welcome.stackoverflow()  # it works 
        
        main_grid = welcome.ids.main
        print(welcome.ids)

        for label, text in md_list:
            main_grid.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon='calendar-text-outline',
                    content=MDLabel(text=text),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text=label)
                )
            )


MyProject().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very grateful for your help. I can understand where I went wrong. Thank you again!